# PowerApp Side Effects error for If-statements?

Tags: if-statement, powerapps

I have an error that is just started happening and is driving me crazy. Multiple If statements say they "have side effects" and will not be evaluated. In most cases, I'm just trying to say that if it meets 2-3 conditions, set variables to x. I don't know how to fix it, and google searches on side effects are not turning up much. Any ideas on how to fix or at least where to research? Any help very much appreciated!!

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XGZ7z.png)

Answer (score 0):

IsEmpty and visible are both booleans already so no need to check they are true.

You can do:

```
If(isEmpty(AttachFiles.Attachments) && Image12_1.Visible, 
    Set(varX, true), 
    Set(varY, false)
  );
```

you can also check if the above is false by adding a ! in front of the two boolean properties. ie, `!isEmpty(xxx)`